# How do I tag certain text to distinguish it, but that can also easily be toggled off to exclude from printing?

Tags: macros, highlighting, text-decorations, tags, markup

I've prepared law school course notes/outlines in LaTeX (using Overleaf). I have a school course in which I'll be tested on both the general law in a certain subject across most U.S. states, and also on exceptions to that law that are specific to my state. But when I take the bar exam after graduation, I'll only be tested on the general law and not on the state-specific exceptions.

So I'd like somehow to tag the state-specific parts in some way that will distinguish them from the general rules when I print the notes for use on my school final exam. (For the tagged text, I might use a different font color, highlighting, boxing--I haven't decided for sure.) But I'd also like to be able to print a version of the notes without any of the tagged state-specific exceptions for use after graduation when I'm just preparing for the bar exam and won't need to know state-specific exceptions.

What is the best way to accomplish this?  The goals are (1) to distinguish the tagged text, and (2) to be able to print a version that excludes all of the tagged text.

Edit to add example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul} % for color and highlighting
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % change enum styles
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \subsubsection{Burden Shifting}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Will contestant entitled to presumption of undue influence by showing:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{confidential relationship} between the alleged influencer and the testator;
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item fiduciary
                    \item attorney
                    \item dominant control
                \end{itemize}
            \item and the presence of one or more \textit{suspicious circumstances}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item unnatural disposition in will
                    \item secrecy
                    \item testator's susceptibility to influence
                \end{itemize}
        \end{enumerate}
        \item \hl{Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The highlighted part at the bottom about Texas would ideally be tagged so that it can be omitted when I want to print a version that excludes Texas exceptions to the general U.S. rules.  I was hoping to do it with a single custom tag that can be used to set a format or with a simple tweak to omit entirely.

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide a minimal working example people can compile to play with? This should include a small amount of text e.g. `This text should be highlighted, when highlighting is on. This sentence should never be highlighted.` If you want to use LaTeX, for example, it should begin `\documentclass...` and end `\end{document}`. Please also decide how you want to mark it up as the best approach will be different in the different cases you mention and tell us which engine you're using.

Comment: I've edited with an example.

Comment: Thanks, but can you make it so people can compile it? That means starting with `\documentclass`. How is `\hl` defined? Are you using a package for that? If so, which one and which engine are you using? On Overleaf, I think pdfTeX is default still, so you probably know if you're using something else.

Comment: Edited with \documentclass.  I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
I don't really care to use \hl.  Ideally I could tag it somehow that allows me to choose what the tag does and to toggle off so the tagged block disappears entirely when I don't want exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You can pretty easily set it up for highlighting vs. different font or different font colour vs. nothing. Boxing would be trickier because you don't (presumably) know how wide the box should be since you might start in the middle of a line. This would also be troublesome at paragraph breaks etc. (It depends a bit how long the exceptions are but, since this is law, I suspect they might be somewhat lengthy!)

A very easy way to handle the simple cases would be to define a custom command in your preamble to do the highlighting or whatever. If you want to change what it does, you change the definition in the preamble. If you want to drop the state exceptions, you comment out the content of the definition so it absorbs its argument without doing anything.

Then you can write say,

```
\tchl{Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
```

and easily change whether this produces anything and, if it does, how it is formatted, by altering the definition of `\tchl` in your preamble.

With definition equivalent to `\hl` from your example,

```
\NewDocumentCommand \tchl { +m }{%
  \hl{#1}% comment out this line to drop the exceptions
}
```

[image: with definition equivalent to \hl{}]

Altering the definition to use blue sans-serif font,

```
\NewDocumentCommand \tchl { +m }{%
  {\sffamily\color{blue}#1}% comment out this line to drop the exceptions
}
```

[image: re-defined to use blue sans-serif]

Commenting the definition out,

```
\NewDocumentCommand \tchl { +m }{%
%   \hl{#1}% comment out this line to drop the exceptions
}
```

[image: with contents of definition commented out]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul} % for color and highlighting
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % change enum styles
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand \tchl { +m }{%
  \hl{#1}% leave uncommented for highlighting ; comment out to drop exceptions ; comment out and uncomment next line for blue sans-serif
%   {\sffamily\color{blue}#1}% uncomment line for blue sans-serif
}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Burden Shifting}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Will contestant entitled to presumption of undue influence by showing:
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \textit{confidential relationship} between the alleged influencer and the testator;
    \begin{itemize}
      \item fiduciary
      \item attorney
      \item dominant control
    \end{itemize}
    \item and the presence of one or more \textit{suspicious circumstances}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item unnatural disposition in will
      \item secrecy
      \item testator's susceptibility to influence
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item \tchl{Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

## Edit

It is probably best to define, say, `\tchlitem` to deal with the case where the command inserts the `\item`.

[image: variations on \tchl]

Definitions:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \tchl { +m }{%
%   \hl{#2}% leave uncommented for highlighting ; comment out to drop exceptions ; comment out and uncomment next line for blue sans-serif
  {\sffamily\color{blue}#1}% uncomment line for blue sans-serif
}
\NewDocumentCommand \tchlitem { +m }{%
  \item {\bfseries\color{magenta}#1}%
}
```

Content:

```
  \tchl{Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
  \tchlitem{Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
  \tchl{\item Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
```

I don't recommend using different colours unless there's some reason, but I wanted to make clear which command was responsible for which line(s) in the output. Don't try to include `\item` in the content with `\hl{}`. Highlighted text is liable to breakage and will give errors. If you want a robust solution, stick to font and colour changes.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for.  Is there a way to do it so I can wrap the tag around the \item so that when I want to omit it, I don't see a blank bullet point?

Comment: Do you always want an item or only sometimes?

Comment: @T.C. Note that you can do that already for the font family/font colour definition (or the nothing definition), though it does turn the bullet point blue. (Not sure whether that is a plus or minus.)

Comment: I was hoping to have two versions--one with tagged items emphasized through font color (as in your example), and another version where I adjust the custom command definition to omit the item entirely.  I don't mind a blue bullet point in version 1, but in version 2, I don't want a bullet point at all.

Comment: @T.C. See above. I was going to suggest an all-in-one solution, but I didn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of the **docstrip** package can be a different approach to the matter.

The **docstrip** package is a means for deriving different .tex-input-files from one (set of) master-file(s). Within the master-file(s) you can place so-called tags. These tags are used for determining the derived files where the tagged portions of text from the master-files will be copied to.

Both within the head of the master-file and in another file you can have so-called `\generate`-directives for creating those files that are to be derived from the master-file.

More info about **docstrip** can be found at CTAN:
https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip

If you save the following example as a file with a name both other than **WithoutTexasNotes.tex** and other than **AlsoWithTexasNotes.tex** and compile it with **tex** or **pdftex** or **latex** or **pdflatex**, two new files will be created, one of them is called **WithoutTexasNotes.tex**, the other one is called **AlsoWithTexasNotes.tex**.

```latex
%<*ignore>
% Section with docstrip directives for generating different 
% .tex-input-files:
\input docstrip

\declarepreamble\WithoutStuffThatIsSpecificToTexasOnly

_________________________________________________________________

Course notes, release without notes that are specific to Texas only.

Use pdflatex/pdftexify for compiling this file.

\endpreamble

\declarepreamble\AlsoWithStuffThatIsSpecificToTexasOnly

________________________________________________________________________________________________

Course notes, release also with notes that are specific to Texas only.

Use pdflatex/pdftexify for compiling this file.

\endpreamble

\generate{%
  \nopostamble
%
  \usepreamble\WithoutStuffThatIsSpecificToTexasOnly
  \file{WithoutTexasNotes.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{StuffThatIsSpecificToAllStates}}%
%
  \usepreamble\AlsoWithStuffThatIsSpecificToTexasOnly
  \file{AlsoWithTexasNotes.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{StuffThatIsSpecificToAllStates,StuffThatIsSpecificToTexasOnly}}%
}%
% Here you can probably insert \write18-calls suitable for your platform
% for calling pdflatex from console for compiling the files
% just generated -- something like:
%    \immediate\write18{pdflatex teacher.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{pdflatex students.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{pdftexify teacher.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{pdftexify students.tex}
%
\csname stop\endcsname % <- end this TeX-run in case you used (pdf)LaTeX
                       %    for generating the files.
%
\bye % <- end this TeX-run in case you used (pdf)TeX for generating the 
%    %    files.
%
%</ignore>
% Section containing the actual LaTeX document, with tags for
% generating different variants with different target groups
%<*StuffThatIsSpecificToAllStates>
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul} % for color and highlighting
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % change enum styles
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \subsubsection{Burden Shifting}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Will contestant entitled to presumption of undue influence by showing:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{confidential relationship} between the alleged influencer and the testator;
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item fiduciary
                    \item attorney
                    \item dominant control
                \end{itemize}
            \item and the presence of one or more \textit{suspicious circumstances}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item unnatural disposition in will
                    \item secrecy
                    \item testator's susceptibility to influence
                \end{itemize}
        \end{enumerate}
%<*StuffThatIsSpecificToTexasOnly>
        \item \hl{Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
%</StuffThatIsSpecificToTexasOnly>
%<StuffThatIsSpecificToTexasOnly>        \item \hl{Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
%</StuffThatIsSpecificToAllStates>
```

The content of **WithoutTexasNotes.tex** is:

```latex
%%
%% This is file `WithoutTexasNotes.tex',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% CourseNotes.tex  (with options: `StuffThatIsSpecificToAllStates')
%% 
%% _________________________________________________________________
%% 
%% Course notes, release without notes that are specific to Texas only.
%% 
%% Use pdflatex/pdftexify for compiling this file.
%% 
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul} % for color and highlighting
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % change enum styles
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \subsubsection{Burden Shifting}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Will contestant entitled to presumption of undue influence by showing:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{confidential relationship} between the alleged influencer and the testator;
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item fiduciary
                    \item attorney
                    \item dominant control
                \end{itemize}
            \item and the presence of one or more \textit{suspicious circumstances}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item unnatural disposition in will
                    \item secrecy
                    \item testator's susceptibility to influence
                \end{itemize}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The content of **AlsoWithTexasNotes.tex** is:

```latex
%%
%% This is file `AlsoWithTexasNotes.tex',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% CourseNotes.tex  (with options: `StuffThatIsSpecificToAllStates,StuffThatIsSpecificToTexasOnly')
%% 
%% ________________________________________________________________________________________________
%% 
%% Course notes, release also with notes that are specific to Texas only.
%% 
%% Use pdflatex/pdftexify for compiling this file.
%% 
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul} % for color and highlighting
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % change enum styles
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \subsubsection{Burden Shifting}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Will contestant entitled to presumption of undue influence by showing:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{confidential relationship} between the alleged influencer and the testator;
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item fiduciary
                    \item attorney
                    \item dominant control
                \end{itemize}
            \item and the presence of one or more \textit{suspicious circumstances}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item unnatural disposition in will
                    \item secrecy
                    \item testator's susceptibility to influence
                \end{itemize}
        \end{enumerate}
        \item \hl{Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
        \item \hl{Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is ingenious, but would you actually set up something like this to achieve the OP's goal? I'm glad you wrote it, because I suspect I might finally be able to make sense of how docstrip works. It just seems something of a sledgehammer. if you want a multi-file solution, you could just set it up with regular LaTeX and `\input` the main file after defining a command or two differently in the wrapper. But that still seems excessive to me.

Comment: @cfr Whether I would set up such a thing depends on many circumstances. E.g., whether there are things (like `vervatim`-environmenrs) where stuff is to be tokenized in different catcode-régime so that probably `\if..\else..\fi` but not a mechanism based on processing macro arguments would work out.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle text, I would use a flag and `if` conditions in latex. I would keep the solution presented by @cfr separately, so you can also highlight normal text, not only lists. Therefore, you will have three commands, `tch` and `tchitem` to highlight text and `specificText` to select whether the text should be hidden or not.
If you want a single command, and you are working only with lists, then feel free to combine `tchitem` and `specificText` in one.

The flag `\showtext` controls whether the code appears, if set to `true` or not, if set to `false`. I must mention that what this does is tell latex to not see the part of the code enclosed in the `if` condition.

With `showtext` set to `true`:
[image]

With `showtext` set to `false`:

[image]

CODE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul} % for color and highlighting
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % change enum styles
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand \tchlitem { +m }{% % Credit to @cfr
    \item {\bfseries\color{magenta}#1}%
}

\newif\ifshowtext % Creates "flag"
\showtexttrue        % Uncomment to show text enclosed in the command \specificText
%\showtextfalse   % Uncomment to hide text enclosed in the command \specificText

\newcommand{\specificText}[1]{% Wraps target text.
    \ifshowtext
    #1
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
    \subsubsection{Burden Shifting}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Will contestant entitled to presumption of undue influence by showing:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{confidential relationship} between the alleged influencer and the testator;
            \specificText{% < ----
            \begin{itemize}
                \tchlitem  {fiduciary}
                \tchlitem  {attorney}
                \tchlitem  {dominant control}
            \end{itemize}
        }% < ----
            \item and the presence of one or more \textit{suspicious circumstances}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item unnatural disposition in will
                \item secrecy
                \item testator's susceptibility to influence
            \end{itemize}
        \end{enumerate}
        \specificText{% < ----
        \tchlitem{Texas: there is no burden shifting and the contestant must establish each element with evidence.}
        }% < ----
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might do `\makeatletter\newcommand{\specificText}[1]{\ifshowtext\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{#1}{\@bsphack\@esphack}}\makeatother`.

Comment: And with your definition of `\specificText` you get a space token behind `#1` which in horizontal mode may yield visible horizontal glue. You get that space token because after tokenizing the `1` of `#1` the reading-apparatus of TeX is in state M (middle of line) so that the end of the line yields a space token.

Comment: @UlrichDiez That's why they invented `expl3` ....

Comment: very informative, thanks to both of you for the comments :)